# customer-data.js error: .../section/load/?sections=instant-purchase&... JS error

Tags: magento2, javascript, customer-data, instant-purchase

I keep getting a JS error in my site, it's an ajax get request to http://domain.com/customer/section/load/?sections=instant-purchase&update_section_id=false&_=1517327157790 which results in a "code 400 Bad request".

It gets called by the Instant Purchase module - which is disabled in my Magento 2.2.2 site.

What could cause this?

My understanding is that the `sections.xml` file does this, but if the module is disabled, it should stop, right?

What am I missing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

See my answer for a different question concerning similar issues:

https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/213550/14403

I believe this will work for you concerning instant-purchase as well.

Answer (score 1):

`sections.xml` doesn't allow you to remove a section from being called sadly.  Well not fully.

What happens is once upon a time you had that module enabled.  As your visitors used your site, they populated the `mage-cache-storage-section-invalidation` key in their localStorage with values like `{"instant-purchase":true}`.

So whenever Magento makes a call to `customer/section/load` it looks to this key to know which sections to pull new data from the server for.  Since you removed the module - and Magento didn't plan for us to remove their modules...  (shame on you.  and me.) - you get a 400 response because the key of `instant-purchase` doesn't exist on the server side.

You can prevent the PHP error and the 400 response by making a plugin to the Customer module.

```
# app/code/Namespace/Customer/etc/di.xml
    <type name="Magento\Customer\CustomerData\Section\Identifier">
        <plugin name="namespace-customer-plugin-customerdata-section-identifier" type="Namespace\Customer\Plugin\CustomerData\Section\Identifier" sortOrder="10" disabled="false"/>
    </type>
```

```
# app/code/Namespace/Customer/Plugin/CustomerData/Section/Identifier.php

class Identifier
{

    public function beforeMarkSections(
        \Magento\Customer\CustomerData\Section\Identifier $subject,
                                                          $sectionsData,
                                                          $sectionNames = null,
                                                          $updateIds = false
    ) {
        $sectionsToExclude = [ 'instant-purchase' ];
        foreach( $sectionsToExclude as $excludedSectionName ) {
            if( in_array( $excludedSectionName, $sectionNames ) ) {
                $sectionNames = array_filter( $sectionNames, fn( $s ) => $s != $excludedSectionName );
            }
        }
        return [$sectionsData, $sectionNames, $updateIds];
    }

}
```

Additional modules/sections you've removed can be added here as well.

However, this doesn't fix the bigger issue that the browser is calling for a section that it doesn't need to.  Ideally deleting the section from localStorage would be the best solve here.  I didn't write my example here to do that...  Wouldn't be hard for someone to add that big.  Instead I just removed that section from the list of sections to be called to the server.

In `vendor/magento/module-customer/view/frontend/web/js/customer-data.js` modify the `reload` function and add this bit of logic at the very top of it.
This will remove your specified sections from the list of sections sent to `customer/section/load`.

```
var sectionsToExclude = [ 'instant-purchase' ];
for( var i = 0; i < sectionsToExclude.length; i++ ) {
    var indexMessages = sectionNames.indexOf( sectionsToExclude[i] );
    if( indexMessages > -1 ) {
        sectionNames.splice( indexMessages, 1 );
    }
    if( sectionNames.length == 0 ) {
        break;
    }
}
```

Also edit `vendor/magento/module-customer/view/frontend/web/js/section-config.js`

Replace this core line of code: `return _.union(_.toArray(actions), _.toArray(sections['*']));`

With this logic:

```
var mergedSectionNames =  _.union(_.toArray(actions), _.toArray(sections['*']));
var sectionsToExclude = [ 'instant-purchase' ];
for( var i = 0; i < sectionsToExclude.length; i++ ) {
    var indexMessages = mergedSectionNames.indexOf( sectionsToExclude[i] );
    if( indexMessages > -1 ) {
        mergedSectionNames.splice(indexMessages, 1);
    }
    if( mergedSectionNames.length == 0 ) {
        break;
    }
}
if( mergedSectionNames.length > 0 ) {
    return mergedSectionNames;
} else {
    return false;
}
```

Of course properly extend these files - don't edit the core files.

I use NewRelic to monitor JS errors.  I've seen ~4k errors a day.  After this change it's dropped down to ~300 a day.  There are some other sources of this error, but this is a very common one.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed this using window on load:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
require([
        'jquery'
    ],
    function($) {
        $(window).on("load", function() {
            require([
                'Magento_Checkout/js/model/cart/totals-processor/default',
                'Magento_Customer/js/customer-data',
                'Magento_Checkout/js/model/quote',
                'Magento_Checkout/js/model/shipping-rate-processor/new-address',
                'Magento_Checkout/js/model/shipping-rate-processor/customer-address',
                'Magento_Checkout/js/model/shipping-rate-registry'
            ], function(defaultTotal, customerData, quote, defaultProcessor, customerAddressProcessor, rateRegistry) {
                $(document).ready(function() {

                    /** Do your code here */
                });

            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: will this work ?
https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/302798/magento2-requiremagento-customer-js-customer-data-not-loading-always