# Magento2 Customer-data-js uncaught-error-object-object

Tags: magento2, customer-data

getting below console error when customer LoggedIn in Magento 2.4.1.

> Uncaught Error: [object Object] at Object.
> (customer-data.js:86) at fire (jquery.js:3099) at Object.fireWith [as
> rejectWith] (jquery.js:3211)
>
> throwing error from below function.
>
> return $.getJSON(options.sectionLoadUrl, parameters).fail(function
> (jqXHR) {
> throw new Error(jqXHR);
> });

Any solution?

Comment: any notable logs in your exception.log and / or system.log ?

Comment: no notable logs in exception log

Answer (score 0):

After a long time i resolve this problem.
this problem occur due to your browser cache during developing.
Clear the Local Storage, Session Storage, and Cookies.

Clear your browser cache or use another browser.
i think its work!

Reference link

[Solution](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/201674/magento-2-customer-data-js9023-object-object)